# How we can add Widgets in in Back Pack Laravel Admin

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

in Back Pack Laravel Admin Panel, I need to add widget in that CRUD Page.
[image]
in above page i want to add that widgets.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative to Wesley's answer, in Backpack 4.1 you can add widgets before/after the breadcrumbs by pushing them to the `before_breadcrumbs` or `after_breadcrumbs` section, from `CrudController::setupListOperation()`.

For example, here's how you can add one DIV widget that contains multiple widgets:

```
Widget::add()->to('before_breadcrumbs')
             ->type('div')
             ->class('row col-md-12 ml-1')
             ->content([
                   [], // registered users widget 
                   [], // vehicles widget
                   [], // journeys widget
                   [], // trips widget
]);
```

Of course, you could just push each widget individually too, to the same stack.

Comment: Ahh, good to know! @Jay, I'd use this method actually :)

Comment: @tabacitu

can you help me, please
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64367704/crud-backpack-laravel-graph-update-when-ajax-filter-get-changed

Answer (score 1):

**Tabacitu's answer below is better, you should use it.**

---

Original answer..

You can accomplish this by copying `vendor/backpack/crud/src/resources/views/crud/list.blade.php` to `resources/views/vendor/backpack/crud/list.blade.php` and adding in whatever content you'd like above the `breadcrumbs` section of the template

```
@extends(backpack_view('blank'))

<!-- add your widget content here -->

@php
  $defaultBreadcrumbs = [
    trans('backpack::crud.admin') => url(config('backpack.base.route_prefix'), 'dashboard'),
    $crud->entity_name_plural => url($crud->route),
    trans('backpack::crud.list') => false,
  ];

  // if breadcrumbs aren't defined in the CrudController, use the default breadcrumbs
  $breadcrumbs = $breadcrumbs ?? $defaultBreadcrumbs;
@endphp
```

If you would like to only add content for certain CRUD pages or make the content change based on the current crud page, you could extend the CrudPanel and CrudControllers to achieve that or you could [use macros to programmatically add functions to the existing CrudPanel](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-operations#adding-methods-to-the-crudpanel-object) to control the widget content